# Vue.js Accordion should not close if another accordion item is clicked

Tags: vue.js, toggle

I want to make an Accordion menu in vuejs. The Accordion should not close if another div is clicked. It should close when the Accordion item itself is clicked. How do I achieve this?

**vue code**

```
new Vue({
el: '#demo',
data () {
return {
  isOpen: false,
  selected: '',
  headerDesktopMenu: {
    menu: {
      menu_items: [{item_name:11111, childrens: [{item_name: 11}, {item_name: 12}]},{item_name:22222, childrens: [{item_name: 21}, {item_name: 22}]},{item_name:33333, childrens: [{item_name: 31}, {item_name: 32}]},{item_name:44444, childrens: [{item_name: 41}, {item_name: 42}]}]
    }
  }
}
},
methods: {
toggleAccordion (item) {
  item == this.selected ? this.isOpen = !this.isOpen : this.isOpen = true
  this.selected = item
}
},
computed: {
accordionClasses () {
  return {
    'is-closed': !this.isOpen,
    'is-primary': this.isOpen,
    'is-dark': !this.isOpen
  };
}
}
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

**HTML code**

```
<div id="demo">
<ul class="level-0-wrp" v-if="headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items">
  <li class="level-0" v-for="(menu, index) in headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items" :key="index" :class="accordionClasses" v-if="headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items">
      <a class="title" @click="toggleAccordion(menu.item_name)">{{ menu.item_name }}</a>
      <ul class="level-1-wrp" v-if="menu.childrens">
          <li class="level-1" v-for="(submenuone, indexone) in menu.childrens" :key="indexone" v-if="isOpen && menu.item_name === selected">
              <a class="title">{{ submenuone.item_name }}</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: So you want to allow multiple accordion sections to be open at a time?

Comment: @bassxzero exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to keep a list of which top level menu items to display or not display. Something like this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-carson-n2exv?file=/src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul class="level-0-wrp" v-if="headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items">
      <li
        class="level-0"
        v-for="(menu, index) in headerDesktopMenu.menu.menu_items"
        :key="index"
        :class="accordionClasses"
      >
        <a class="title" @click="toggleAccordion(menu.item_name)">{{
          menu.item_name
        }}</a>
        <ul
          class="level-1-wrp"
          v-if="menu.childrens && displayArray[menu.item_name]"
        >
          <li
            class="level-1"
            v-for="(submenuone, indexone) in menu.childrens"
            :key="indexone"
          >
            <a class="title">{{ submenuone.item_name }}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      selected: "",
      displayArray: {},
      headerDesktopMenu: {
        menu: {
          menu_items: [
            {
              item_name: 11111,
              childrens: [{ item_name: 11 }, { item_name: 12 }],
            },
            {
              item_name: 22222,
              childrens: [{ item_name: 21 }, { item_name: 22 }],
            },
            {
              item_name: 33333,
              childrens: [{ item_name: 31 }, { item_name: 32 }],
            },
            {
              item_name: 44444,
              childrens: [{ item_name: 41 }, { item_name: 42 }],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAccordion(item) {
      if (this.displayArray[item] === undefined) {
        this.$set(this.displayArray, item, true);
      } else {
        this.$set(this.displayArray, item, !this.displayArray[item]);
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    accordionClasses() {
      return {
        "is-closed": !this.isOpen,
        "is-primary": this.isOpen,
        "is-dark": !this.isOpen,
      };
    },
  },
};
</script>
```