# How to set sidebar menu active when clicked in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vue.js

I want to set sidebar menu active when clicked. Now only the first menu is selected as active. If other menus are selected, the first menu still remains as active menu. How to implement this ?

**My code:**

```
<div id="mobile_sidebar_display">
  <div
    class="logo_section d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
  >
    <a v-on:click="closeSideDrawer" :href="base + '/'">
      <img src="../../assets/images/logo_2.svg" class="w-100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 10px"></div>
  <a
    v-on:click="closeSideDrawer"
    class="sidebar_link active"
    :href="base + '/'"
    ><i class="fas fa-home"></i> <span class="ml-2">Home</span></a
  >

  <a v-on:click="closeSideDrawer" class="sidebar_link" href="#"
    ><i class="far fa-user"></i> <span class="ml-2">Courses</span></a
  >
  <router-link class="sidebar_link" to="/QuizGrid"
    ><i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i>
    <span v-on:click="closeSideDrawer" class="ml-2"
      >Puzzles</span
    ></router-link
  >
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need a variable for each menu item, a single array with indexes for each menu item, or to move the menu item into its own component and put the show/hide logic in that new component.

Comment: I need an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703642/vue-js-accordion-should-not-close-if-another-accordion-item-is-clicked/69704308#69704308